# Rendering a CALayer to an image with arbitrary size

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, calayer

I'm using the following `CALayer` extension in my macOS app to render a `CALayer` into an image:

```
extension CALayer {

    /// Get `Data` representation of the layer.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - fileType: The format of file. Defaults to PNG.
    ///   - properties: A dictionary that contains key-value pairs specifying image properties.
    ///
    /// - Returns: `Data` for image.

    func data(using fileType: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType = .png, properties: [NSBitmapImageRep.PropertyKey : Any] = [:]) -> Data {
        let width = Int(bounds.width * self.contentsScale)
        let height = Int(bounds.height * self.contentsScale)
        let imageRepresentation = NSBitmapImageRep(bitmapDataPlanes: nil, pixelsWide: width, pixelsHigh: height, bitsPerSample: 8, samplesPerPixel: 4, hasAlpha: true, isPlanar: false, colorSpaceName: NSColorSpaceName.deviceRGB, bytesPerRow: 0, bitsPerPixel: 0)!
        imageRepresentation.size = bounds.size

        let context = NSGraphicsContext(bitmapImageRep: imageRepresentation)!

        render(in: context.cgContext)

        return imageRepresentation.representation(using: fileType, properties: properties)!
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that this function renders an image that have the same dimensions as the layer itself, as rendered on screen.

How could I modify it to be able to specify the size of the image to render and have the layer expand to the dimensions of the image?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an additional parameter for the desired size and to scale the content to that size:

```
func data(using fileType: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType = .png, size: CGSize, 
    properties: [NSBitmapImageRep.PropertyKey : Any] = [:]) -> Data {
    let width = bounds.width * self.contentsScale
    let height = bounds.height * self.contentsScale
    let imageRepresentation = NSBitmapImageRep(bitmapDataPlanes: nil,
        pixelsWide: Int(size.width), pixelsHigh: Int(size.height),
        bitsPerSample: 8, samplesPerPixel: 4, hasAlpha: true, 
        isPlanar: false, colorSpaceName: NSColorSpaceName.deviceRGB,
        bytesPerRow: 0, bitsPerPixel: 0)!
    imageRepresentation.size = size

    let context = NSGraphicsContext(bitmapImageRep: imageRepresentation)!

    context.cgContext.scaleBy(x: size.width / width, y: size.height / height)
    render(in: context.cgContext)

    return imageRepresentation.representation(using: fileType,
        properties: properties)!
}
```

With this modification you can call this method like:

```
let theBounds = myView.bounds
let theSize = CGSize(width: theBounds.width * 3.0, height: theBounds.height * 3.0)
let theData = myView.layer?.data(using: .png, size: theSize, properties: [:])
```

to save the contents of `myView` to three times scaled up of the original size into a data object.

Comment: I was so hopeful this would work, but I injected it in my code and it produces a downscaled image. What I'm trying to achieve is to build an worldmap based on a set of layers in a UI, and then export the view of that component into an image that I can set as a wallpaper. I injected your code in my public project here: https://github.com/epseelon/scratchmap/blob/master/ScratchMap/ImageUtils.swift and used it here: https://github.com/epseelon/scratchmap/blob/master/ScratchMap/WorldMap.swift

Comment: If you want to created an upscaled image just change the size in the call. I've changed my example.

Comment: I tried it already, but for some reason, it seems to render an image that's the right size but the layer is only rendered in the bottom left quarter corner.